# Запуск не от root в Apache2

Tags: oracle, apache

Проблема в том, что в перловом скрипте mod_perl не может подключиться к Оракловой базе, в тестовых скриптах, выполняемых из под соответствующего пользователя(oracle) в шелле такой коннект нормально выполняется. В логах апача ошибка Ora-12154 TNS: Could not resolve the connect identifier бла бла бла. В гугле пишут, что переменные окружения не те. Прописывание их руту ничего не дало. Хочу запустить под пользователем oracle,  но не получается, т.к. apache2ctl находится в /usr/sbin.

Спс за ответы, все заработало по варианту № 4 из доки к [Oracle:DBD](http://search.cpan.org/~pythian/DBD-Oracle-1.30/Oracle.pm):

```
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:DB','username','password')
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:DB','username/password','')
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:','username@DB','password')
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=foobar;sid=ORCL;port=1521', 'scott/tiger', '')
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:', q{scott/tiger@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST= foobar)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)))}, "")
```

Comment: Apache хочет рута только на секунду, чтобы инициализироваться (порт получить и т.п.), затем он сбрасывает привилегии и использует UID/GID из конфига.

Answer (score 2):

Может скажу глупость, но что мешает в конфиге апача указать другого user для запуска?

Comment: Для Апаче2 в SLES11 это не сработало:
httpd процессы по-прежнему от root и wwwrun запущены

Comment: Вот это посмотрите: [запуск виртуальных хостов Apache2 от разных пользователей][1].


  [1]: http://sudouser.com/zapusk-virtualnyx-xostov-apache2-ot-raznyx-polzovatelej.html

Answer (score 0):

Если очень хочется запустить от пользователя oracle так дай ему права на запуск...

Comment: права на папку /usr/sbin rwxr-xr-x, на все файлы в ней, в т.ч. apache2ctl тоже